# In batch scripting what does the expression %* expand?

Tags: image-processing, batch-file

I have a batch script which has got a line

```
echo %* >> test.txt

%PROCESS% %*
```

What does the expression %* denote and expand to?

Answer (score 1):

It simply expands to the arguments passed in to the shell/batch file. e.g.

foo.bat:

```
echo %*
```

and then doing

```
c:\> foo.bat abcefg hijkl 1 2 3
echo abcefg hijkl 1 2 3
abcefg hijkl 1 2 3
c:\>
```

Comment: That was quick. Thank you.